# What does the >= operator mean in this return statement?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I know what greater than equal to operator is? I am asking what does it mean here?What does the **>=** operator mean in the last line? I am sure it is *not a lambda function* What is the meaning of this return statement?

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

It is in the **Django docs** here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/, under the 'Playing with the API' section.

Comment: It means "greater than or equal".

Comment: What does this mean here?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators

Comment: In JavaScript, the arrow of a lambda expression is `=>`, not `>=`.

Comment: It compares what is to the left with what is to the right. If greater or equal, it evaluates to `True`, otherwise `False`.

Comment: [`>=`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/greater_eq.html) is a "Greater than or equal" comparison operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>=` means greater than or equal to.

In this code

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

first, one day is subtracted from the current time, and then `self.pub_date` is compared to that time. If `pub_date` is within one day of the current time, then this will return true. Otherwise, the function will return false.

Based on order of operations, this would be equivalent:

```
return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

It means "greater than or equal".

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

We are comparing `pub_date` with yesterday.